# Python - Looking for guidance on getting Mouse Position

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with the small solution to find the Mouse Cursor position on GUI.

Below is my code. I do get the mouse position but only when the mouse is moved and NOT Clicked.  In fact I want to know can I turn this solution to get the X,Y coordinates only when the mouse is clicked?
 Another problem I face here with this code is the moment I click anywhere in the screen my GUI hungs and I cannot do anything after that. Please let me know is there a possible solution for this? Forgive me If my coding style is not according to the standards.

```
# Globals
# ------------------

x_pad = 0
y_pad = 0

import win32api, win32con
import wx
import time
import sys

def mousePos(cord):
   win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))


class URL(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(URL, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 

    self.InitUI()




def InitUI(self):   

    pnl = wx.Panel(self)
    sbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Start', pos=(10, 30))
    cbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Close', pos=(10, 80))
    stdot = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, pos =(100,30),size=(150,100),     style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
    sys.stdout = stdot
    sys.stderr = stdot

    sbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)
    cbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

    w = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_X)
    h = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_SCREEN_Y)
    APPWIDTH = 300
    APPHEIGHT = 200

    posx = w - APPWIDTH
    posy = h - APPHEIGHT


    self.SetSize((300, 150))
    self.SetTitle('Get XY Coordinates')
    self.SetPosition((posx, posy))
    self.Show(True)

def OnStart(self,e):
    while 1 == 1:
        x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        x = x - x_pad
        y = y - y_pad
        print x,y
        time.sleep(2)

def OnClose(self, e):

    self.Close(True)

def main():

ex = wx.App()
URL(None)
ex.MainLoop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out PyMouse.  I have used it before with some success.  https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse

Answer (score 0):

You could use wx's own `wx.GetMousePosition()` for this, seems like a more sensible approach to me.

Comment: I replaced x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()  with x,y = wx.GetMousePoistion  but it just acted as a replacement. My app gets stuck when I click anywhere on the screen. Do you think I should do something else as well?